# Testing if std::pointer_traits can work with my type

Tags: c++, pointers, smart-pointers, c++17, type-traits

How can I check at compile-time whether or not an arbitrary type can be used with `std::pointer_traits`? I had hoped a simple SFINAE solution might work:

```
template <typename T, typename = void>
struct pointer_traits_ready : std::false_type {};

template <typename T>
struct pointer_traits_ready<
         T,
         std::void_t<typename std::pointer_traits<T>::element_type>
       > : std::true_type {};

static_assert(!pointer_traits_ready<int>::value,"");
```

...but this invokes a static assert from within the standard library (ptr_traits.h). Obviously `std::is_pointer` doesn't accommodate smart pointers.

Comment: You could try the detection techniques described in [N4502](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/n4502.pdf).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't. From [[pointer.traits.types]](http://eel.is/c++draft/pointer.traits.types):

> ```
> using element_type = see below ;
> ```
>
> *Type:* `Ptr::element_type` if the *qualified-id* `Ptr::element_type` is valid and denotes a type (14.8.2); otherwise, `T` if `Ptr` is a class template instantiation of the form `SomePointer<T, Args>`, where Args is
>   zero or more type arguments; **otherwise, the specialization is ill-formed.**

In order to be SFINAE-friendly, we would need `pointer_traits<Foo>`  to simply lack a type alias named `element_type`. The problem is, `element_type` is specified as being ill-formed - not absent. So you simply cannot use `pointer_traits` as a detector for whether or not something can be used as a pointer type.

Even if you wrote your own type that was a SFINAE-friendly version of that specification, you wouldn't be able to catch user specializations of `pointer_traits` for their own type. Sad panda.

Comment: User specializations must obey the rules of the standard, which are pretty restrictive in this case no?

Comment: @Yakk I think I'm allowed to write `struct pointer_traits<Foo> { using element_type = int; };` as long as my `Foo` dereferences into that?

Comment: And I thought I could write a `std::less` specialization that didn't call `operator<`, but apparently I was wrong about that...  I don't understand the "your specializations must not violate the guarantees in of the version in std" clause (whatever its wording is) and how it applies here.  It may be the case that you are *only* allowed to `element_type=int` *if* `Foo::element_type` is `int`.  I don't think this was intended, but it *may* be what the standard requires.

Comment: @Barry That is a pity. Thanks for the answer.